# Opening modal form without navigating to new page in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation

I have a website where a user has a 'Groups' page, and in order to create a new group, that user currently has to click on the `New Group` button, which directs them to the `localhost/groups/new` page.  I'd like to get rid of that page, and replace it with a modal popup form.

In the groups view, I have a partial `_form.html.erb` that looks like this:

```
<%=form_for @group do |f|%>

<div class = "title">
    <%=f.label :title%>
    <%=f.text_field :title%>
</div>

<div class = "description">
    <%=f.label :description%>
    <%=f.text_field :description%>
</div>

<div class = "memberships">
    <%for user in @users%>
        <%= label_tag user.name%>
        <%= check_box('members', "[#{user.id}]") %>
    <% end %>
</div>

<div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit 'Submit', class: "button radius"%>
</div>

<%end%>
```

And then my `new.html.erb` file just looks like this:

```
<h1>New Group</h1>

<%= render 'form' %>
```

How can I make this form a popup modal instead of an entirely new page?  I figured I could just render the form in a reveal-modal like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/foundation/foundation.js"></script>
    <script src="js/foundation/foundation.reveal.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/foundation.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#" class="button" data-reveal-id="newGroup">New Group</a>
    <div class="reveal-modal" id="newGroup" data-reveal>
        <%= render 'form' %>
        <a class="close-reveal-modal">x</a>
    </div>
    <script>
        $(document).foundation();
    </script>
</body>
```

But that did not work, because I get an error:

```
First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty

--> <%=form_for @group do |f|%>

<div class = "title">
    <%=f.label :title%>
    <%=f.text_field :title%>
</div>
```

Do I need to change something in my controller for this to work?  Or can I just render the page I need to within a modal somehow?

**EDIT**: Here is the `index` method in my controller.  What would I need to change here?

```
def index
    if(params[:user_id].nil?)
        @groups = Group.where(owner_id: current_user.id)    
    else
        @groups = Group.where(owner_id: params[:user_id])
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

In your view file

```
<div class="reveal-modal" id="newGroup" data-reveal>
  <%= render template: 'groups/new' %>
  <a class="close-reveal-modal">x</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Just tried it, and I'm getting: `Missing partial groups/_new` error.  It looks like this assumes `groups/new` is a partial, which it isn't.  My `groups/form` is, but that can't be rendered because then I get an error: `First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty` which trips on the line `<%=form_for @group do |f|%>`

Comment: `<%= render template: 'groups/new' %>` would solve the problem, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Your guess about changing something in the controller is likely correct.

You'll need to make sure that the `@group` instance variable is defined by the action in the controller that is rendering the form. This might look something like:

```
class GroupsController < ApplicationController
  # ...

  def index
    @group = Group.new
    # The rest of the implementation of this action.
  end

  # ...
end
```

This makes the assumption that whatever page you want the modal to appear on is being rendered by the `index` action of the `GroupsController`.

Comment: I just added the `index` method from my controller.  What exactly do I need to do?  I don't necessarily want to create a new group every time I load the page - only when the modal is opened and then submitted.

Comment: `Group.new` won't create a new group in the database, it will only make it so that you can use `form_for` by providing an unpersisted instance of an ActiveRecord object. `Group.create` or `Group.save` or `Group.update` and a few others are the methods that will actually persist data to your database.